# Error while installing mysqlclient on Fedora25

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pip, fedora, fedora-25

I am trying to install mysqlclient in my virtual environment which runs on python3.5.2 but it always throws error as:

```
(venv) [kevran@localhost mysite]$ pip install mysqlclient   
  Collecting mysqlclient        
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found   
    Traceback (most recent call last):   
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>  
      File "/tmp/pip-build-m92fr1vk/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()   
      File "/tmp/pip-build-m92fr1vk/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config     libs = mysql_config("libs_r")    
      File "/tmp/pip-build-m92fr1vk/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config    
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))    
    OSError: mysql_config not found

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-m92fr1vk/mysqlclient/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yu need to install `mysql-devel` package in OS.

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

or something like that.

Comment: I did tried that it says:                                                                                          `Last metadata expiration check: 1:11:33 ago on Sun Jul 16 18:33:02 2017.`
`No package libmysqlclient-dev available`

Comment: It's called `mysql-devel` in Fedora, sorry. `libmysqlclient-dev` is for Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: But is still not working. It says no package available. I tried to search by using `dnf search mysql-deve1` but no luck

Comment: `mysql-devel` (last letter is lower L), not `mysql-deve1` (not a digit).